# Doubt about invertibility of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, matrices

I consider the matrix $\Gamma(\mu)$ with $\mu\in[0,+\infty)$ such as
$$[\Gamma(\mu)]_{jl}=-\frac{i\mu}{4\pi}I+diag[\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_N]+A(\mu)$$
with $i$ imaginary unit and 
$$[A(\mu)]_{jj}=0\,\,\,\,[A(\mu)]_{jl}=\frac{e^{i\mu|y_j-y_l|}}{4\pi|y_j-y_l|}\,\,\,\textrm{for}\,\,j\neq l$$
$y_j$ are fixed points in $\mathbb{R}^3$.
Can I Always take the parameters $\alpha_j$ in such a way that the matrix is invertible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** Yes. Let $A$ be $n\times n$. The off-diagonal entries of $A(\mu)$ and $\Gamma(\mu)$ are bounded by $M=1/(4\pi\min_{j,\ell}|y_j-y_\ell|)$. So, if the moduli of the real parts of the $\alpha_i$s are large enough (say, larger than $(n-1)M$), then $\Gamma(\mu)$ is [diagonally dominant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonally_dominant_matrix) for all $\mu>0$. Therefore, by [Gerschgorin disc theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), $\Gamma$ will be invertible.

Comment: What does it change if I take $\mu\in\mathbb{C}$ with imaginary part strictly positive?

Comment: @Sue Wait. Do you mean you want to set $\alpha_i$s in a way that $\Gamma(\mu)$ is invertible **for all** $\mu$?

Comment: I want the invertibility for all $\mu\in [0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @Sue If $\mu$ is complex with strictly positive real part, the diagonal entries of $-\frac{i\mu}{4\pi}I$ would have strictly negative imaginary parts. Therefore if $\mathrm{Im}(\alpha_i)<0$ and every $|\mathrm{Im}(\alpha_i)|$ is large enough, then again $\Gamma(\mu)$ is strictly diagonally dominant and hence invertible.

Comment: I know that $\alpha_i$ are real constants; I've unterstood your suggestion in the case $\mu>0$. Now I'm trying to study the case in which $\mu$ is complex with stricltly positive imaginary part.